# Mac OS X program giving EXEC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, exc-bad-access

In one of my modules I need to maintain event-based mechanism. The logic is:

To send the event:

```
-(void)addEvent:(EventData *)pData{

    [self enQueueEvent:pData];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     postNotificationName:EVENT_NAME
     object:nil ];

}

-(void)enQueueEvent:(EventData *)pData{
    [pEventLock lock];
    [self.pEventArray insertObject:(NSObject *)pData atIndex:0];
    [pEventLock unlock];
}
```

When event received:

```
-(void)EventHandler: (NSNotification *) notification
{
    [self log:@"event Handled"];
    EventData *pData = [self deQueueEvent];

    if(pData){
        switch(pData->eModuleId){
            case UI_EVENT:{
                [UIController HandleUICallBack:(EventType)pData->eType LParam:pData->lParam WParam:pData->wParam];
            }
        }
        pData->lParam = 0x00;
        pData->wParam = 0x00;
        free(pData);
    //  [pData release];
        //[self removeProcessedEvent];  
    }
}

-(EventData *)deQueueEvent{
    [pEventLock lock];
    NSObject *pData = [self.pEventArray lastObject];
    [self.pEventArray removeLastObject];
    [pEventLock unlock];
    return (EventData *)pData;
}


>>>>>>> Adding Header File Declaration >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
typedef struct __eventData{
    ModuleId eModuleId;
    EventType eType;
    void *lParam;
    void *wParam;

}EventData;

@interface CommEventHandler : NSObject {
    NSMutableArray *pEventArray;
    bool shouldStartTimer;
    int timerValue;
    NSLock  *pEventLock;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *pEventArray;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSLock  *pEventLock;

<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< End of Header File <<<<<<<<<<<<
```

I believe this is easy to understand. Now what is happening is that when I run the program in `10.6 | App Name | Debug | i386` it runs perfectly fine, but when I run the program in  `10.6 | App Name | Debug | X86_64` it faults while inserting a node into the Event array. Can anyone give me a clue how to debug ? I checked all memory aspects, but failed to find anything.

Comment: Is `pEventArray` a declared property? If so, what’s its setter semantics: `assign`, `copy`, `retain`?

Comment: And what’s the actual declaration of `CommEventData`?

Comment: And what’s the actual declaration of `EventData`, too?

Comment: @Bavarious : Thanks for Looking at it, added header file declaration. CommEventData and EventData both are same.

Answer (score 2):

If `CommEventData` is the same as `EventData`, then both aren’t Objective-C classes. As such, you cannot add values of type `CommEventData *` to an `NSMutableArray` because `NSMutableArray` expects an Objective-C object — in particular, an Objective-C object that responds to both `-retain` and `-release`. This will crash if what’s being added is not an object regardless of the `(NSObject *)` typecast.

If you convert `EventData` and `CommEventData` to Objective-C classes, you can use `NSMutableArray`.

Otherwise, if you want to store pointers to values that are not Objective-C objects (e.g. pointers to `structs`), consider using `NSPointerArray` instead. Note that since `NSPointerArray` allows arbitrary (pointers to) values, it doesn’t take ownership of nor release its elements.

Comment: If this is so, shouldn't it be crash in the i386 mode ?

Comment: @Rohan If you cast a pointer type (`CommEventData *`) to another pointer type (`NSObject *`), there’s no conversion to the underlying values. Whether the program will crash depends on the contents of the memory the pointer is pointing to, so essentially you have undefined behaviour.